# I have discovered a security vulnerability in Oracle 19c and would like to obtain a CVE number. How should I proceed?

Tags: oracle, security

I have discovered a security vulnerability in Oracle 19c and would like to obtain a CVE number. How should I proceed?

How can I get official recognition for this vulnerability from Oracle or a CVE in the shortest time possible?

Answer (score 2):

As with any third-party software, report bugs found to the maintainer of that software in a responsible manner.

In this case, Oracle gives guidance on [how to report security vulnerabilities](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/security-practices/assurance/vulnerability/reporting.html):

> #### How to Report Security Vulnerabilities to Oracle
>
> If you are an Oracle customer or partner, please use your designated
> support mechanism (e.g., [My Oracle
> Support](http://support.oracle.com/) or
> [SuiteSupport](https://system.netsuite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp?country=US))
> to submit a service request for any security vulnerability you believe
> you have discovered in an Oracle product. If you are not a customer or
> partner, please email secalert_us@oracle.com with your discovery. We
> encourage people who contact Oracle Security to use email encryption
> using our [encryption
> key](https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/encryptionkey.html).
>
> Oracle values the members of the independent security research
> community who find security vulnerabilities and work with Oracle so
> that security fixes can be issued to all customers. Oracle's policy is
> to credit all researchers in the Critical Patch Update Advisory
> document when a fix for the reported security bug is issued. In order
> to receive credit, security researchers must follow responsible
> disclosure practices, including:
>
> - They do not publish the vulnerability prior to Oracle releasing a fix for it
> - They do not divulge exact details of the issue, for example, through exploits or proof-of-concept code
>
> Oracle does not credit employees or contractors of Oracle and its
> subsidiaries for vulnerabilities they have found.

Regarding getting a CVE number, from https://www.cve.org/About/Process:

> 1. **Discover**
>
>    A person or organization discovers a new vulnerability.
> 2. **Report**
>
>    Discoverer reports a vulnerability to a CVE Program participant.
> 3. **Request**
>
>    CVE Program participant requests a CVE Identifier (CVE ID).

Oracle is a [CVE Program participant](https://www.cve.org/PartnerInformation/ListofPartners/partner/oracle) so you can report it to them and they can request a CVE Identifier. Alternatively, report it to another CVE Program participant and they can research the problem and request a CVE number and/or report it onwards to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, you will find next steps: https://www.cve.org/About/Process